# How to cast interface obj to class obj?

Tags: c#, class, interface, casting

I have two classes that implements same interface:

```
 public class UserVM : Iuser
 public class User : Iuser
```

I need to cast `UserVM->interface->interface->User` with some functions, I can do this:

```
 Iuser obj = new UserVM()
```

and then I need to do:

```
User user = obj;
```

it didn't work(i have also tried `User user = obj as User` but didn't work).

How can i cast it correctly?

Comment: "Didn't work" is not a sufficient problem description. Please add the exact Error Message and on which line it happens (=> stacktrace).

Comment: Imagine `Iuser` is `IFlyable`, and `UserVM` is `Bird` and `User` is `Airplane`. How do you convert an `Bird` to a `Airplane`? You can't.

Comment: Fildor,  that new User object still null after      `User user = obj as User`

Comment: YOu either have to make User : UserVM or UserVM : User.  Two children of  same parent cannot map to each other.  You can only cast a parent to a child (not a child to parent or sibling).

Comment: Just because two classes implement the same interface, it doesn't mean you can change one into the other via casting through that interface. These casts are *representation preserving* casts - you still have the *same* object, no matter what you've cast it to.

Comment: You seem to have a basic misunderstanding about how interfaces and classes work. Even if you declare the variable to a UserVM as Iuser, the runtime type will stay the same. It cannot be magically converted to a User type simply by casting. (Given they are unrelated except for same interface)

Comment: You may wish to read Eric Lippert's post on [Representation and Identity](https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/) to get it clearer what's happening when casting.

Comment: "new User object still null after `User user = obj as User`" That how `as` works. `obj` does not have an "is-a" relation to `User`, so the "as" operator will result in null.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thx

Comment: @Sweeper: sure, you can instantiate an Airplane with all common proprerties(so at least all which are in `IFlyable`). For example: `var sp = new AirPlane{WingSpan = bird.WingSpan}`. If such an airplane makes any sense is a different subject.

Comment: @Rango That's not what he meant. That would still be a new airplane with the same properties, but not that exact bird, turned into an airplane - do I make sense?

Comment: @Fildor: of course cast doesn't work. But Sweeper said "convert". And you can convert X to Y if you provide a method or expression which describes the way. It's not the same instance of course.

Comment: @Rango Ok, I read "convert" differently. If you understand it in that sense, you are right, of course.

Comment: Good question for interviews. A lot of candidates can be filtered out. :)

Comment: Thank you all for your time guys! i already got the problem solved, thanks!!

Comment: @Fildor: think of all methods in the [`Convert` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the reason is the same as it is for most of other "why convert to obj from this particular interface fails" questions.

A bowl of apples *is* a bowl of fruit. But a bowl of fruits is not *necessarily* a bowl of apples and that's why you get compiler error. Same thing applies to singular objects.

You're trying to convert a concrete object to another type for that you could use ctor injection or operator overloading (among other things):

```
public class User
{
   public User(Iuser obj)
   {
      this.myProperty1 = obj.myProperty1;
      ... assign all field here
   }
}
```

To use it just do:

```
Iuser obj = new UserVM()
User user = new User(obj);
```

Comment: It just occurred to me that maybe, if he feels like having to do this, he may be doing interface separation wrong? Maybe UserVM and User should share a "DataObject"?

Comment: "A bowl of apples is a bowl of fruits": in plain english yes, in OO code it's not. A bowl of fruits has very likely a method `AddNewFruit (Fruit whatever)`, but a bowl of apples cannot have such method. It would allow to add a banana to a bowl of apples, which can be nice while eating, but not while writing software...

Comment: @GianPaolo This is an off-topic a little bit and it is an implementation detail. Example I used is for explanation of covariance in generics in C#. Bowl is an analogy of C# collection. Since in both cases we use the same word `Bowl` it is logical to assume that these two 'bowl objects' have the same types